# Printing AIC results is missing information

Tags: rpy2

whenever I try to print AIC results from `rpy2`, some trivial information gets lost in the display.  Taking the example from R `help(AIC)`:

```py
import rpy2.robjects.conversion as cv
from rpy2.robjects import Formula, default_converter, pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr, data

r_stats = importr("stats")

datasets = importr("datasets")
swiss = data(datasets).fetch("swiss")["swiss"]

lm1 = r_stats.lm(Formula("Fertility ~ ."), data=swiss)
lm2 = r_stats.update(lm1, Formula(". ~ . -Examination"))

with cv.localconverter(default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    aic = r_stats.AIC(lm1, lm2)
```

Printing the aic object, I get:

```py
In [2]: aic
Out[2]: 
                                                     df         AIC
list(c(66.9151816789687, -0.172113970941455, -0...  7.0  326.071568
list(c(62.1013115551538, -0.154617487544675, -0...  6.0  325.240844
```

whereas in R, this is printed as:

```
>     df   AIC
lm1  7 326.1
lm2  6 325.2
```

Given that models are ordered by AIC, it is important to identify the model as printed by R, but this is lost in rpy2.  Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because a) the `data` objects is anonymous (that is as far as R is concerned, the Python object `swiss` passed to it is just a data structure without an associated symbol/name, and b) the R function `lm` likes to use the unevaluated arguments to report information about the model.

There are different ways to work around this. The documentation for rpy2's dev version covers this:

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/robjects_environments.html#environments-as-temporary-local-contexts

Comment: Thank you! Is local_context() only available in the dev version?

Comment: Currently, yes. It will be in rpy2-3.4.0.